# Check if existing stripe customer's cards are still valid

Tags: stripe-payments

I have an application which uses Stripe. Stripe stores credit card information for every customer. Some of these cards are already expired and not valid anymore.

How can I go through all customers and validate their credit cards (if they are still valid or not)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In many cases, Stripe will automatically update the cards: https://stripe.com/blog/smarter-saved-cards.

Otherwise, there is no way of checking that a saved card is still valid short of trying to charge it. But you should not try to create charges just to test if a card is still valid -- the credit card networks rules and Stripe's own ToS forbid from creating charges that are not for the actual selling of a good or service.

Comment: It's been 5 years already, is this still the case? No way to validate the card short of attempting to charge it?

Answer (score 0):

From Stripe documentation

In many cases, Stripe will automatically update the cards: https://stripe.com/blog/smarter-saved-cards.

Otherwise, there is no way of checking that a saved card is still valid short of trying to charge it. But you should not try to create charges just to test if a card is still valid -- the credit card networks rules and Stripe's own ToS forbid from creating charges that are not for the actual selling of a good or service.

Although you can always test the card without charging using the "save card" function

More here - https://support.stripe.com/questions/check-if-a-card-is-valid-without-a-charge